# Erase content in pdf page with itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Shortly, I want to erase the content of pdf page by background color without changing its page size. Here is more detail:

[image]

Says pdf page size is A4 paper, content can be texts or images, and the erased content is 1 cm spacing around (blue part)
I wonder is there any way to do this?

**Update**: my try with clipping path

```
 // render text and image
 //...
 // then erase    
 PdfContentByte clipCB = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();
clipCB.saveState();
clipCB.setColorStroke(Color.WHITE);
clipCB.rectangle(100,100,600, 600);
clipCB.clip();
clipCB.newPath();
clipCB.restoreState();
```

Comment: *my try with clipping path* - a clipping path Clips the content following it, not preceding it. And restoring the former graphics state right after creating the clipping path immediately stops clipping.

Comment: Thanks, as I don't have many experience in iText, so I don't know how to make it work as aspect. Do you have any suggestion? I removed restoreState but still not work (content isn't clipped)

Comment: *I removed restoreState but still not work (content isn't clipped)* - as mentioned, you have to define the clip path **before** adding the content to clip. Thus,  your `render text and image` has to happen between `clipCB.newPath();` and `clipCB.restoreState();`.

Comment: That been said, you cannot use `document.add(...)` to add your text and the clipping path as shown above in any combination to clip the text as itext strictly separates what you do manually on the direct content and what its own layouting does.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options.  The easiest thing to do would be to draw 4 rectangles in the background color around the edges.  A more elegant approach would be to set a clipping path prior to rendering the page's contents.

Here's an example using a clipping path: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0419__PDF/Cliparegion.htm

Comment: Could you give me more detail? As I don't know how to apply clipping path for my case. I tried (in updated question) but it didn't work.

Comment: I your updated code, I don't see where you are adding text/other rendering operations to the content byte... Start with the example clipping path code that I linked to in my response, then add additional content to it.